# Repeater in update panel fails to show on initial page load

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, hashtable, repeater

I have a repeater with a paged datasource on a content page in dotnet 4.0 coded with c# behind. The data is loaded via a hashtable that pulls data from an sql 2005 database on a shared server.  Currently the first time the page loads, no data shows and/or the repeater fails to show. If I refresh the page though the data displays fine.

Has anyone else come across this sort of problem before? Ideally I'd like to prevent the page from rendering until the data is loaded in but haven't been able to find a solution.

I can provide code and links to project for anyone interested in this problem.

Thanks

Si

Comment: Hi Simon. It doesn't sound like the expected behaviour, could you as much of your code as you can?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you're binding the information at the wrong time? Can't be sure without code.

Comment: Yes exactly that. Should have checked closer. I was using a session object to get a value to pull the correct data from the db but the session value isn't generated until after the page has loaded hence why I needed to refresh to see the data. Stupid mistake really! Thanks for your speedy reply though, it did point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I fixed it. I was populating the repeater with data based on the value of a session object that isn't created until after the page has loaded. School boy error really.